# How do I add an extra line to the end of a th?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a large table that takes several seconds to completely render.  The above the fold renders nearly instantly, but once the table is fully rendered an extra line is added to `th` so the entire table shifts down one line, making the user click where they did not expect.  I would like to add the extra line to the inline style of the first `th`, but I can't figure out how.

`th:after` gets replaced after the render is complete, so that would be the ideal place to put an extra line, but I just can't seem to make that work.  Also, it looks like you can't alter `th:after` with inline css, I'll probably have to put an `id` on the first `th` anyway.

I've been testing with https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table .  I inserted the below after `<html>` but none of it makes a newline, at least not in Chrome 65.

```
<head><style>
th:after{content:"1<p>2</p>3<div>4</div>\a5<br>6";}
</style></head>
```

Adding a space in there will make a new line, but only due to wrapping.  If you zoom out far enough it goes back to one line.

Thank you.

Edited to add:

I experimented with `padding-bottom`, but the height was not consistent between browsers.  `1.4em` was the closest I came, but it is slightly too big in Chrome on Windows and slightly too small in Chrome on Linux.

Mr Lister's answer works perfectly everywhere with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but all my pages use `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`.  With the latter it still works perfectly in Chrome and Internet Exploder, but doesn't appear to do anything in Firefox.  Firefox does work correctly if I switch to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`, but then the W3C HTML validator gives me 5044 Errors.

So I guess the question should have been, is there an HTML 4.01 Transitional way to do this?

If I add `test` after the two `\0A` in Mr Lister's answer, it is correctly rendered two lines down in Firefox.  So adding `content` to the `after` is working correctly, but the two `\0A` only show up if there is text after them (a space does nothing and html is displayed literally).

Edited to add solution:

The reason `em` wasn't working is because different fonts have different heights.  Fonts often vary between operating systems and browsers, so a fixed height will never work.  The only way I found to get the correct height was to actually put the final characters there and make them invisible:

```html
<script>
newStyle=document.createElement('style');
newStyle.type='text/css';
newStyle.innerHTML="span.ph{visibility:hidden;}";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newStyle);
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>This is a th<span class='ph'><br>&#x25B4;</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is a td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
newStyle.innerHTML='span.ph{display:none;}';
</script>
```

Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Maybe you can add `&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;` in your `<th>` tag while loading and replace the value once table is  loaded.

Comment: As you probably noticed, you can't use markup in `content`.  What you _could_ try is a style such as `table.prerender th { padding-bottom: 1em; }` and put `class="prerender"` on the table to start, then remove the class via javascript when the rendering completes.  Without a sample/demo here it's hard to say (try adding a "stack snippet" to your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a placeholder that is 'empty' at first, and filled when the data is ready?

Example:

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById('placeholder').innerText = "result";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header cell<br />
      <span id="placeholder">&nbsp;</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Body cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<button onclick="change()">Add header content</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to include *two* newlines, since the first one will be invisible, and to set the white-space property on the ::after pseudo element.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

th::after {
  content: '\0A\0A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>This is a th</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is a td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```